# How to start Samsung SM-T210 via pc , without wi-fi but with ethernet?

Tags: internet

My home ethernet , is wired only !  How i can start and connect my tablet , through my pc ?

Answer (score 0):

Some Android devices with USB-on-the-go (or USB host mode) support can use a USB ethernet adapter, when connected through a USB-on-the-go connector. If your device supports this, you can buy a USB ethernet adapter and connect it to your network that way.

If your device doesn't support that, you can use [reverse-tethering](/questions/tagged/reverse-tethering) to connect your device through USB to your PC's network connection (the PC acts like a router). See the existing questions with this tag to learn more about that.